# How to name the Cited References in \{thebibliography} section in LateX and not just number the citations

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Suppose this is the perfect syntax for citing some references in LaTeX:

```
\cite{HH123}
```

And below is the code for the references:

But the problem is that I don't want the references to be in a numbered fashion but in a naming fashion. So how to go about it.

```
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{li}
\bibitem{HH123}
\end{thebibliography}
```

The output of the above text is:

> [1] XYZ

And I want them to be as:

> [HH123] XYZ

Comment: Why is this tagged `biblatex`? Also, please complete your code to make a small, compilable document demonstrating the issue.

Comment: You can use four spaces to indent code blocks as I have done to make things much more readable.  Also, as @cfr mentions, you really need to have a [Minimum Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe/3301#3301) so that others can follow what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your setup correctly, you're constructing the bibliography "by hand", i.e., by putting together various `\bibitem`s in the `thebibliography` environment. In that case, you could write

```
\bibitem[HH123]{ABC}Name and other information about this bibliographic entry
```

so that the citation command `\cite{ABC}` will generate

```
[HH123]
```

instead of `[1]` (or whatever the item's number in the list happens to be).

Putting this all together into an MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
\noindent
Here's the citation call-out: \cite{ABC}
\begin{thebibliography}{li}
\bibitem[HH123]{ABC}Author name and other information about this bibliographic entry.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```